# Next JS custom carousel and looping/showing/hiding through items

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a custom build Next JS carousel that keeps an index of the slide we are on and renders an image or video to the screen. It seems that because it is autoplaying and each slide gets removed and readded every 6 or so seconds the page downloads constant copies of the same video or image when it comes around again. Is this not the correct way of doing this?

So the important part is here

```
{slides.map((item, key) => (
    <>
    {key == this.state.currentImageIndex && (
        <div>
```

It will remove and readd content every slide. Does it waste resrouces constantly downloading them? Is there a better way?

```
import React from 'react'

//Importing data to use as the slides
import { slides } from './data/slides'
import VideoSlide from './VideoSlide'
import ImageSlide from './ImageSlide'

let slideTimer = null

class Carousel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentImageIndex: 0, //Array index of slide from /data/slides
      slideTime: 6, //Timing duration of a slide
    }
    this.setMyInterval = this.setMyInterval.bind(this)
  }

  //Runs when this componenet is included in the page
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setMyInterval()
  }

  changeSlide(current) {
    /*Don't run if we are just clicking the same slide number*/
    if (current != this.state.currentImageIndex) {
      this.setState({ currentImageIndex: current }) //Change to selected slide1
      clearTimeout(slideTimer) //Reset the timer so it's not half way through the countdown when we select another slide
      this.setMyInterval() //Rebuild the slide countdown so we are starting at 0 and in sync with our CSS animation
    }
  }

  setMyInterval() {
    slideTimer = setInterval(() => {
      const lastIndex = slides.length - 1 //Check when we need to loop
      const { currentImageIndex } = this.state //Get current slide from state
      const shouldResetIndex = currentImageIndex === lastIndex
      const index = shouldResetIndex ? 0 : currentImageIndex + 1 //Reset to 0 if we are at the end

      this.setState({
        currentImageIndex: index, //Set new slide as number obtained from above
      })
    }, this.state.slideTime * 1000) //Repeat every x seconds
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(slideTimer)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="backgroundSlide">
          {slides.map((item, key) => (
            <>
              {key == this.state.currentImageIndex && (
                <div>
                  <VideoSlide url={slides[0].video} />
                  {slides[this.state.currentImageIndex].image && (
                    <ImageSlide
                      url={slides[this.state.currentImageIndex].image}
                      timer={this.state.slideTime}
                    />
                  )}
                </div>
              )}
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
export default Carousel
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question that what kind of Carousel logic you have. Usually, we render the whole carousel elements and then let the carousel do its job. As an example consider this CSS only carousel,

https://css-tricks.com/css-only-carousel/

If you use such an approach, you can have all of your `slides` rendered one time and don't have to worry about the removal/addition of any slides.

Comment: I guess I'm not too concerned on recoding it if the way i have it is viable. Just wondering if it's loading and unloading the assets constantly?

Comment: As per your code, you keep changing the item as the carousel moves. If you check the network tab in developer tools in any browser, you might see a new item being either downloaded or taken from the cache.